# Symfony2 jQuery div refresh without

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

i have a form and i use jQuery for submit and work without refresh page..

```
$('#formnotifica').submit(   
        function(event){  
             event.preventDefault(); 
             term = $(this).serialize(); 
             url = $(this).attr('action');
             $.post( 
                     url,
                     term,
                     function(data){
                        }
                     )
        }  
   );
```

Now i would refresh only my  content the form and the date after click of submit or some second..
I use this code when i tried but give me another page Symfony and give me problems..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#aggiorna").load("");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#aggiorna").load("" + Math.random());
    }, 1000);
});
```

Where **#aggiorna** is the "ID" of my  .. How can i do for refresh my result of query in controller?? Thanks and sorry for my english

---

THIS IS THE CODE HTML

```
<div id="aggiorna">
                   <ul>
                        {% for n in notifications %}
                        {% if n.is_displayed == 0 %}
                            <li>
                      <form id="formnotifica" action="{{ path('profilo_index', {'id': n.id}) }}" method="post">
                            <input name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ n.id }}" />
                            <button class="submit" id="submit" type="submit" >{{n.text|raw}}</button>
                                </form>
                                </li>
                        {% else %}
                        <li>{{n.text|raw}}
                                </li>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                           </div>
```

In the controller there is only DQL query for update a field in my db

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: If i remove this line, my page refresh every time when i click on submit.... @scoolnico